# Chartkick Datepicker/Range Selector - Possibility to choose dates to show data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts, datepicker, chartkick

I am using `ahoy gem` to track visits & `chartkick gem` to show the data to users.

In users dashboard page, I have around 3-4 charts and each of them show different data to user.

As of today, my charts only displays last 7 days & I do it by `group_by_day(:started_at, last: 7)`.

```
= area_chart Visit.where(user: current_user).group_by_day(:started_at, last: 7).sum(:price), label: '$'
```

How can I add `datepicker` so users can select two dates *(start & end date)* and display data between selected/giving dates?

*UPDATE:*
I have created `charts_controller.rb` and get the charts from this `controller` & `routes`.

*For instance:*

```
class ChartsController < ApplicationController
  def visits
    result = Visit.where(user: current_user).group_by_day(:started_at, last: 7).count
    render json: [{name: 'Visits', data: result}]
  end
```

*My `routes.rb`:*

```
resources :charts, only: [] do
    collection do
      get 'visits'
    end
  end
```

*My view:*

```
= area_chart visits_charts_path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `datepicker` and add an onchange listenner on it, then you send the start and end date using ajax to a controller that renders your chart:

```
$(".end_at").change(function(e){
    end_at = $(e.target).val(); 
    start_at = $(".start_at").val();     

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/charts",
        data: {
          start_at: start_at,
          end_at: end_at,
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $(".chart-container").html(data);
        },
      });    
});
```

In your controller :

```
class ChartsController < ApplicationController
  def visits
    start_at = params[:start_at].to_date
    end_at = params[:end_at].to_date
    render :inline => "<%= area_chart Visit.where(user: current_user).group_by_day(:started_at, range: start_at..end_at).sum(:price), label: '$' %>"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @Othmane. Can you please read my question, I have added some new setup. When I test with your code, I get error that link doesn't exist even when I go to my browser, I can see the link

Comment: did you add the ajax block ?

Comment: or if you don't want to use ajax, you can add a form in your view where you put your datepickers and then get them in your controller and render the chart

Comment: Thanks for helping.Yes, I added your ajax. Just to be on same page, by ajax, you mean the ajax code in your answer?

Comment: I updated my answer. Update your `answer` action as below

Comment: Okei, I fixed the error I got from console, It was a `Post` error and I added `post` to my `routes.rb`. But now when I select a date, the chart doesn't show at all

Comment: can  you post the js function you added ?

Comment: `render :inline` gave me error for undfined method for `started_at` & `end_at`, so I used: `result = Visit.where(user: current_user).group_by_day(:started_at, range: start_at..end_at).sum(:price)` `render json: [{name: 'Visits', data: result}]` With this I dont get the error but chart is not showing :/

Comment: Sure, 2 sec I will create a bin so you can see all my codes

Comment: use again  `render :inline`, and this time you convert start_at and end_at to time objects, `start_at.to_time..end_at.to_time` it  must work

Comment: This is all my  [codes on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rubioli/ct0aoa01/) Just take a look at `html` part please. Thanks for help man

Comment: I still get: undefined local variable or method ´start_at´ when I use: `start_at.to_time..end_at.to_time`

Comment: how is it possible to have an  undefined local variable while you just defineded it ^^

Comment: haha Thats a good question. the full error was `undefined local variable or method ´start_at´` and this line was highlighted: `    render :inline => "<%= area_chart Visit.where(user: current_user).group_by_day(:started_at, range: start_at.to_time..end_at.to_time).sum(:price), label: '$' %>"
`

Comment: you just need to add the classes end_at and start_at to your datepickers, i updated the fiddle

Comment: Thanks man :), Works Like a charm man. I just needed to change `start_at..end_at` to `params[:start_at]..params[:end_at]`. I only have one question. As mentioned, in same page I have several charts, How can I just dont use `ajax` and get to update the charts from controller? I appreciate you help

Comment: you need a form for that where you put your start_at and end_at as inputs, and then a controller, but this time no need for an inline render. A simple view with a post request